# Codeigniter Insert Data

Tags: codeigniter, php

**My Controller:**

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {}

public function add()
{
    // $this->input->post('title')

    $models = $this->load->model('Page_Model', 'page');

    echo $models->page->insertData();
}
```

**My Model:**

```
class Page_model extends CI_Model {}

public function insertData()
{
    echo 'sdvsdf';
}
```

**Error:**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function insertData() on a non-object in**

I do not know what happened. Seems working correctly.

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate, because it is about a CI specific method.  The post you mentioned uses typehinting which isn't in question here, and coreprojectz is trying to use the `model` method with a return value like is documented for the `view` method.

Comment: i already saw this article and i do not think i dublicated question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$this->page->insertData();` to call the method.

The `model` method in the `Loader` class returns void.

See the comment, **@return  void** in `system/core/loader.php`

```
/**
 * Model Loader
 *
 * This function lets users load and instantiate models.
 *
 * @param   string  the name of the class
 * @param   string  name for the model
 * @param   bool    database connection
 * @return  void
 */
public function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
 ...
```

Comment: absolutely right. thanks very much.